# iphone Launch Options

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

im not getting any launch options after a push notification; heres the code i have but non of the NSLogs seem to print in the debug area.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif =
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (localNotif) {
    NSString *itemName = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSLog(@"Custom: %@", itemName);
} else {
    NSLog(@"//////////////////////////");

}
```

when i open the app (via pressing view on the push notification) it goes to the didReceiveRemoteNotification script, im not sure if thats meant to happen..

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your application receives push notifications through multiple paths, depending on the state of your app when it is received.

If your app is not launched (not even suspended in background), the `launchOptions` will contain the notification payload (key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`).

If it is already running or suspended in background, the app will receive the notifications via `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` in your application delegate.

The process is the same for local notifications (UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey  in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`)

Comment: thanks, so is the anything so when the application is in the background the app can get the same result... i want it to change the page when the token custompage is page 2 or 3...

Comment: You can peform the same actions in  `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` than in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. Just keep in mind that in the 1st case, your app just started so you know perfectly what is displayed and in the 2nd case, the user could be anywhere in your app.

Comment: ok thanks, one more question how would you recommend i change the view? i got told to do NSUserDefaults but i would want something that would go to it right away. and if the user is on that page then refresh it.

Answer (score 1):

an error spotted:

```
NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:   
                              UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

If you want to receive the remote notification, `NSDictionary` should be used not `UILocalNotification`

The remote notification is a payload, containing arguments, not a local notification. You might want to look at this url question:

[Crash when handling remote notification when app not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295122/crash-when-handling-remote-notification-when-app-not-running)

If you want to do local notification, change it like Ludovic's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The answers given above are correct. I largely use the following snippet in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
if let remoteNotifPayload = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
        notificationsController.didReceiveRemoteNotification(with: remoteNotifPayload)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a local notification (I assume with your var name) replace `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` by `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo { 
      NSLog(@"Alert message: %@",[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to do the trick. In your `AppDeligate.m`, set a bool to `YES` in the first time. So after that it never gets to `NO`.

```
  -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //add this if loop
        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }
```