# How to implement instruction view for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 2 pages that I want to show as instructions the first time the app is run. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking how to know if this is the first time the app had been run or how to show these two pages? If first, then take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964371/how-to-detect-first-time-app-launch-iphone

Comment: [Do you need inspiration](http://mobile-patterns.com/edu), or [code](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: @CodaFi it's better to ask an expert on the proper way to do this as it's been done countless times before

Comment: @Kyle: Is that to imply that I lack credibility?  No matter, the links I have provided are excellent reading.  Though, I would suggest you reword this question before it is closed for literally being `not a question`

Comment: @CodaFi I'm implying you're trolling

Comment: @Kyle: Trolling?  The second link is standard reading for people who need us to "show them teh codez." To think that I would even have the slightest reason to falsify or "lead on" is a serious misjudgment of my character.  Lest this become a flame war, I bid you good day, sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize `NSUserDefaults` for something like this.

```
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"didLoad"]) {

          //Show your instructions

       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"didLoad"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }
```

What this does is, check if the `didLoad` bool is FALSE (Which will be on first Load), if it is you show your instructions and set the `BOOL` to `YES` for the next Launch. You can put this in your `viewDidLoad` method.