# Switching Views Programmatically in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to switch to the second view by pressing the "feeling lucky" button. When I try out my simulator and press it, it just goes to a black screen. How could I fix this?

```
@IBAction func FeelingLuckyPress(sender: UIButton) {

    let secondViewController:SecondViewController = SecondViewController()

    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Where is SecondViewController supposed to get its `view` from? To put it another way, what you have done so that this view should _not_ be a black screen? Explain. Describe.

Comment: Here are the ways a view controller gets its view. If you don't use one of them, the view controller's view is empty and black: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_controller_and_view_creation

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add a segue between the two scenes in your storyboard by control dragging from the view controller icon at the top of the first scene to the second scene:

[image: create segue]

You can then select that segue and give it a unique storyboard identifier, and then you can just perform the segue using that identifier:

```swift
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToSecond", sender: self)
```

---

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```swift
guard let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as? SecondViewController else {
    return
}
present(controller, animated: true) // or `show(controller, sender: self)`
```

where “Second” is a storyboard identifier I specified for that destination scene in Interface Builder.

---

By the way, there are alternatives if you are creating your destination scene programmatically or using NIBs, but storyboards are more common, so I focused on that in my examples above.