# display 'disclaimer' when app loads

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have the following bit of code in my `super viewDidLoad`section of my app:

```
if ( appCounter < 1   ) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Disclaimer", "")
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"By agrreing to use this service, dont use while driving", "")
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"I Agree to not use this while Driving"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        appCounter = appCounter+1;
    }
```

basically, it should show a disclaimer when the app loads. but every time the user navigates away from the main screen, and then comes back to the main scene (its a multiple view app) the disclaimer pops up again.

i would have thought that the app counter would have stopped this, yet it still keeps popping up.

Could someone please point out where in my code i have gone wrong? and what i need to do to rectify this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you declaring appCounter?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` only gets called once when the view is loaded into memory. If this code is running every time then when you're traversing the app you're not using existing VC instances but rather making new ones.

Comment: Maybe you want to popup that screen [only the first time the app is started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964371/how-to-detect-first-time-app-launch-on-an-iphone/9964400#9964400)...

Comment: @LuisCien its declared as a NSIntegar in the .h file.

Comment: @PeterFoti could you please elaborate on the VC instances? I'm relatively new to objective c coding and haven't come across that terminology before.

Comment: @H2CO3 i will have a look into it and get back to you. if it fulfils my needs, re-comment as an answer and ill mark t as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're declaring `appCounter` as an instance variable in your class, e.g.

```
@interface MyViewController () {
    int appCounter
}
```

Then a new MyViewController is created each time, and `appCounter` is reset to zero.

You want `appCounter` to be static: once and for all. You can replace your current version with a static variable declaration:

```
static int appCounter;
```

(i.e. your .m file, and not in the interface definition). That should be once and for all. There are other ways to get `appCounter` to be shared among all instances of your ViewController (some people are funny about declaring static variables, even though they aren't accessible from outside that module), but that's the easiest.

Comment: Thank you very much! very simple to implement, as you said!.