# Swift App first run detection

Tags: swift, xcode6

in swift, how can i detect if this is the first time the app is ran ?
i want to create a simple game that sets the high score to 0 if the app is new. if i typed this :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(0, forKey: "firstrun")
    if ( NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstrun")?.integerValue == 0 ){
        
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(0, forKey: "HighScore")
        else {
      
            outputLabel.text = String(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("HighScore")
      }
}
```

This "firstrun" will be reseted to 0 after every launch, how can i solve this issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964371/how-to-detect-first-time-app-launch-on-an-iphone

V. similar question but in obj C. Should be easy to convert

Answer (score 3):

NSUserDefaults has a `registerDefaults:` method for this purpose. Use it (in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`).

Answer (score 1):

As matt said, `registerDefaults` was created for this purpose.

However, if you don't want to use `registerDefaults`, then I'd suggest using `integerForKey` and `setInteger` instead of using `objectForKey`.  `integerForKey` defaults to 0.  So if you use it, the HighScore will default to 0 until it is set.