# How to check if the IOS app is running for the first time using SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // app already launched
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // This is the first launch ever
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I searched this question and got so many answers in **Objective-C**. Can anyone help me to do that in **swift**? Thank you in advance.

Comment: check        if(NSUserDefaults().standardUserDefaults.boolForKey("isFirstTime") == nil)

Comment: Check the last answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964371/how-to-detect-first-time-app-launch-on-an-iphone

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati `boolForKey` returns `YES` or `NO`. It can't be `nil`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this one

```
if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("HasLaunchedOnce") {
  // App already launched

} else {
  // This is the first launch ever
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Swift 3 version->

```
if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")) {
   // App already launched

} else {
   // This is the first launch ever         
   UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")
   UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```