# Error When Detection First Launch (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to detect if the app is being opened for the first time. I've put this piece of code in my ViewController's `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
        if launchedBefore  {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainController", sender: self)
            print("launchedBefore")
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTutorialController", sender: self)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
            print("not launchedBefore")

        }
    }
```

But, whenever the ViewController launches, no segues are performed. But thext I told it to print, is printed. If it matters, the view that the segue `"toMainController"` goes to is a `UITabViewController`, and the view that the segue `"toTutorialController"` goes to is just a `UIViewController`.

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

**UPDATE**

I found this error

> 2017-06-30 09:02:32.984 AppName[29732:24744712] Warning: Attempt to
>   present  on <
>   AppName.ViewController: 0x7fcbfa908ed0> whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

Comment: UserDefaults.standard().synchronize()

Comment: Add the above code after  **UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")**

Comment: Are you printing out the correct text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the IOS app is running for the first time using SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635160/how-to-check-if-the-ios-app-is-running-for-the-first-time-using-swift)

Comment: @VigneshDavins In swift 3 you do not need `synchronize`, and method after `performSegue` will be executed

Comment: Have you checked if your segues are setup corectly in IB? What happens if you move this code to `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: If the text is printed the error is related to the segues and the associated controllers.

Comment: @VigneshDavins Check out my update. I found some more information.

Answer (score 1):

First save in userDefault and then perform segue:-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
        if launchedBefore  {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainController", sender: self)
            print("launchedBefore")
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTutorialController", sender: self)
            print("not launchedBefore")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
        if launchedBefore  {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainController", sender: self)
            print("launchedBefore")
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTutorialController", sender: self)
            print("not launchedBefore")
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem wasn't the code itself, it was just where it was being executed. It needed to be executed in the `UITabBarViewController`.