# How to change Splash screen dynamically according to the particular user?

Tags: ios, splash-screen

I am developing the school application and admin panel. On first time open application it will to show My company's *splash-screen*, in my app i am giving login credentials for parents. After login into app it will register that user to particular school. Next time when user open the app it should show particular school *splash-screen* what ever that school is added in admin panel.

If is it possible? How it can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

yes its possible you should use the custom splash screen view controller.
Please refer the below link and follow the steps.

https://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/iphone-dev-how-to-implement-a-splash-screen/

or

```
UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_default_image_or_another.png"]];
[[firstViewController view] addSubview:imageView];
[[firstViewController view] bringSubviewToFront:imageView];

// as usual
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//now fade out splash image
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^(void){imageView.alpha=0.0f;} completion:^(BOOL finished){[imageView removeFromSuperview];}];
```

In this you can use your own image or download image from web service for different school and set here in imageview.

Comment: But it is not suitable in iOS7

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Comment: In above link i read here they told Xib or Story boards is possible in iOS8 or later

Answer (score 3):

> In first time open application it has to show My company splash
>   screen, in my app I am given login credentials for parents. After
>   login into app it has to register that user to particular school.

An easy way to go about this would be to set a BOOL in your AppDelegate to test if it's the first launch of your app.

In `AppDelegate.m` you could check if it's the first load of the app by doing something like this in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Check if app has loaded before
    [self checkUserDefaults];
    // Another method to determine what the first screen the user sees is
    [self setInitialViewController];
    return YES;
}
```

...further down you could do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9964400/4475605)

```
// make a section for UserDefaults
#pragma mark - User Defaults

- (void)checkUserDefaults {

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

> Next time user open app it has to show particular school splash screen
>   what ever that school is added in admin panel. If is possible? How?

You could also create a method in `AppDelegate` that determines where to go next, based on `NSUserDefaults`:

```
- (void)setInitialViewController {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;

    // Check if there's a key created or if the key exists
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"]boolValue] == NO || ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"]) {
        // set to instantiate first launch VC
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"initialVC"];
        self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    } else {
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"schoolSelectedVC"];
        self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Somewhere down the line on your Initial Scene, you'd want to update your `NSUserDefaults` to reflect that it's configured for that a school is selected.

```
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"];
```

Answer (score 0):

use your own splash screen view controller.

use userdeafult to save that state of it -like if you want it to work only one time or only everytime the app wasn't in the memory-

use delegate methods or notification centre -any thing with call back function - or normal method and check the conditions you need and with each condition change the UI as you need by show/hide , UIAnimation or even refresh the whole UI

hope this can help you.