# After Receiving Notification how can i get message on app icon click?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, push-notification

My push notification works properly but in my app the push notification comes with two different messages: one is "task completed" and the second is "you have a message".

Now when the application is in background state and notification arrives, how can I get notification's message when I click on the app icon?

If anybody knows then please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: try to get payload data when click on app icon.

Comment: Please check answer of following question Link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5456271/900024

Comment: @PratikMistry : i check this link but it will not help us to this question.my question is which method is call when my application is in background and notification is come.

Comment: If user does not click tap on notification to open the app no method will be called but if user taps the notification while your application is in background the didReceiveRemoteNotification: method will be called where you can check application.applicationState to determine if application came from background or not.

Comment: If user does not click tap on notification to open the app no method will be called but if user taps the notification while your application is in background the didReceiveRemoteNotification: method will be called where you can check application.applicationState to determine if application came from background or not.

Comment: @PratikMistry : i understand your point but what we should to do when user tap on app icon for getting payload data of notification.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 7 and above you can use:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

This will allow you to do a quick amount of processing when the application is in a background state.

Comment: Thank you for replaying, didReceiveRemoteNotification method only called when app is in foreground but i want get the data of payload when app is background.

Comment: You didn't read it correctly. This is an iOS 7 method with a fetchCompletionHandler ... It's a different method to the old didReceieveRemoteNotification.

Comment: OK...right now i dont hav any device for testing but let me know one thing is this method is called when push notification was received and my app was in background?

Comment: yes that's what I said. This gets called and you can do some processing then call a completion handler. Read the docs.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification with completionHandler doesn't get called if you click the app icon. If your application is closed and you click the application icon, it still does not get called. I've tested this with my iPhone6 device. Everything that I have read says you can't get the push notification if a user clicks the app icon.

Comment: Yes you can't from the notification. In this instance you would need a 'copy' of the data on a remote server and to retrieve the information from there. OR to save a copy of all received notifications before the app is launched by using this method.

Comment: Okay, so I've been doing a LOT of testing. And I finally figured this out.
As of iOS 7, you can implement background remote notifications. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/
This allowed me to get the notification even if the user clicks on the application icon! =)

Comment: Fairly sure that was my original answer ?

Comment: For someone who is a beginner there wasn't any explanation why the method 'didReceiveRemoteNotification CompletionHandler' method wasn't getting called. This is why I wasn't understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as of iOS 7, you can get it.

You need to implement Background Remote Notifications.

In your info.plist file, you need to add:

[image: info.plist file requirement for Background Remote Notifications]

Then, in your push notification, add to the payload `'content-available': 1,`

Then, implement the `(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` method in AppDelegate.m.

See Reference:http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/

I have tested this on my iPhone device & it works! =)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The notification data is delivered to your app in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. If you want to process it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` you should store it in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` and read it again in `applicationDidBecomeActive.`

please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084015/ios-push-notification-how-to-get-the-notification-data-when-you-click-on-the-a?lq=1)

Comment: i declare one string variable in header file and i set its value in didReceiveRemoteNotification and print this variable in applicationDidBecomeActive but value is not printed.i think the  didReceiveRemoteNotification not called when application is in background state.

Comment: I think you are correct. Because I tried this as well Bandish. And it doesn't print a value at all. Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After you received the push notification..When you click on app icon then below method will be called...UserInfo (Dictionary) is the payload coming from APNS

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
   didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSLog(@"Message from APNS%@", userInfo);

    NSLog(@"APS from APNS%@", userInfo[@"aps"]);

    NSLog(@"ID from APNS%@", userInfo[@"id"]);

 }
```

In the above log see that what userInfo dictionary is giving and try to retrieve the value from it..

If the app is in foreground mode then it receive push notification via `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

But if the app is not in foreground mode push notifications are passed to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Hope it helps you...

Comment: Thank you for replaying, didReceiveRemoteNotification method only called when app is in foreground but i want get the data of payload when app is background.