# Handle Remote Notification in Background

Tags: ios, push-notification

from a couple of days, I am searching solution for this issue, finally posting it here:

when i get Remote Notifications, and ignore the push notification and launch the app by clicking on application icon, delegate method "didreceiveRemoteNotification" will not be called. is there any way to get full Notification payload dictionary, when app launches.

Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295122/crash-when-handling-remote-notification-when-app-not-running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You should store the notification details on your server and make a request to the server to get pending details (and update details that have been accessed).

The app has no access to notifications in notification centre unless the user explicitly selected to open the app from there.

Comment: in IOS7 multitasking enhancement, we can send silent PN, by sending key "content-available" for payload 1, this will enable the app to make API call in BG, and the new delegate will be called again, when the app launches, here our issue seems to be fix, can we achieve the same in IOS7 below devices.

Answer (score 0):

At launch you will receive the remote notification through the launch options. In your application delegate, implement `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` and then you can retrieve the same dictionary you would otherwise be given in `didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` like this:

```
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];

    ...
}
```

Comment: All this is fine. but when user taps on the app Icon, on launch delegate method "didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo" will not be called, then How will we get notification payload dict.

Comment: Oh I guess I misunderstood. The above answer is correct then, it's not possible and you will have to make some sort of database of unread notifications on the server that the app will need explicitly mark as read when they're received by push or fetched manually from within the app.