# How to get notification payload when app is killed not running in background in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have a question. Is it possible to get the notification body when you open the app from the notification even if is the app is not running in the background. It is completely killed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crash when handling remote notification when app not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295122/crash-when-handling-remote-notification-when-app-not-running)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295122/crash-when-handling-remote-notification-when-app-not-running - this can help you.Basically you need to handle in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ll need to handle a notification differently depending on what state your app is in when it’s received:

If your app wasn’t running and the user launches it by tapping the push notification, the push notification is passed to your app in the launchOptions of `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.

If your app was running either in the foreground or the background, the system notifies your app by calling `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`. If the user opens the app by tapping the push notification, iOS may call this method again, so you can update the UI and display relevant information.

Add the following code to the end of `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, just before the return statement:

```
// Check if launched from notification
let notificationOption = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification]

// 1
if let notification = notificationOption as? [String: AnyObject],
  let aps = notification["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

  // 2
  print(aps)

}
```

To handle the other case for receiving push notifications, add the following method to AppDelegate:

```
func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler:
  @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void
) {
  guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
    completionHandler(.failed)
    return
  }
  print(aps)
}
```

Comment: Hi does this apply to local notification too ?

Answer (score 0):

you should fallow below steps

**1-) in your AppDelegate, added below code snipped**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print(userInfo)
    }
```

2-)Sign&Capability -> Background Modes, allows
[image: Allow Background Modes]

3-) "content-avaliable": 1, add to your payload.

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Testing.. (40)","content-available":1,"badge":1,"sound":"default"}}
```